# Local host always load only Html index.html loads correct

Tags: javascript, html, css

The localhost :
Xaamp, lamp, wamp
always load only Html index.html loads correctly.
I am facing any problem in 000webhost but localhost show this problem
https://coding-sample.000webhostapp.com/
This is the website you can view the source code

Comment: is `https://coding-sample.000webhostapp.com/` your site that you are asking about?

Comment: yes this the website